# Static Session Class and Multiple Users

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

I am building a class to store User ID and User Role in a session. I'm not sure how this class will behave when multiple users are on the site at the same time. Does anyone see a problem with this?

```
public static class SessionHandler
    {   
        //*** Session String Values ***********************

        private static string _userID = "UserID";
        private static string _userRole = "UserRole";

        //*** Sets and Gets **********************************************************

        public static string UserID
        {
            get
            {
                if (HttpContext.Current.Session[SessionHandler._userID] == null)
                { return string.Empty; }
                else
                { return HttpContext.Current.Session[SessionHandler._userID].ToString(); }
            }
            set
            { HttpContext.Current.Session[SessionHandler._userID] = value; }

        }
        public static string UserRole
        {
            get
            {
                if (HttpContext.Current.Session[SessionHandler._userRole] == null)
                { return string.Empty; }
                else
                { return HttpContext.Current.Session[SessionHandler._userRole].ToString(); }
            }
            set
            { HttpContext.Current.Session[SessionHandler._userRole] = value; }
        }

}
```

Comment: Untestable and encourages bad practices like using static 'global' helpers. It's not a technical issue, more of a mindset issue with long term effects

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The code you posted is the exact replica of some code we have here.

It has been working fine for 2 years now.

Each users access is own session. Every request made to the server is a new thread. Even though 2 request are simultaneous, the HttpContext.Current is different for each of those request.

Answer (score 4):

You'll get a new session for each connection. No two users will ever share session. Each connection will have its own `SessionID` value. As long as the user stays on your page (doesn't close the browser, etc.) the user will retain that session from one request to the next.

Comment: Not necessarily... If you are doing cross site authentication... You can have a newly authenticated user using the same session. I've run into this issue before. The session is independent of the authentication. If a user is able to end the session and kill the authorization on the first site... the authorization will be gone from the second site, but the session is separate.

Answer (score 0):

This will work fine for mutiple users accessing your application as there will be different sessionid generated for all deffrent users accessing application concurrentely. It will work in similar way if you have defined two different session variables in your system.
It will be like wrapping tow session states using  static wrapper class SessionHandler.